# Sudo yarn build / Error : EACCES : permission denied, unlink

Tags: symfony, permissions, hadoop-yarn

After a **pull** from the main branch of the project, I have an issue while trying to `yarn build` after a `composer install` and a `yarn install`.

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/dir/anotherdir/file.css'
```

And it says at the end :

```
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

I tried to run it with `sudo yarn build`, to `rm -rf /nodes_modules`, then to `yarn cache clean`, finally to `yarn start` or `yarn build`, and even to `chmod 777` both the **file** and after that the **directory** but nothings seems to work.

I'd like to precise that I'm using a linux container on a VM.
The project is using Symfony, Yarn, and there is no interaction with the database in this case.

Comment: Where do you work ? On your VM or in your linux container? In my case I have the same rights issue if i try to work on my vm and not in my container

Comment: @CharlieLucas As you might see below, I finally solved the issue and it's partly related to what you were saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did find a solution in the end. As I was working on a LXC (Linux Container), **the rights were not the same** on my IDE's (Phpstorm) command line and the LXC command line.

When I tried to **change the roles directly from my host**, I messed up the rights of the directories in the container. Changing to a user **that is know on both sides** solves the issue.

NB : Seems obvious but always yarn build on the container